# React 'fetch' response successful, but setState not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, working through a "[.Net core CRUD with React](https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-crud-with-reactjs-and-entity-framework)" tutorial and trying to tweak it along the way to suit my own needs.

The page I'm dealing with here is an Add/Edit entry page. It works fine for rendering a default form with default values but doesn't render anything if the values are collected from a fetch call.

The important details are below:

```
interface AddPortfolioProjectDataState {
    title: string;
    projectData: PortfolioProject;
    loading: boolean;
}
```

The page is told to render as follows:

```
public render() {
    let contents = this.state.loading
        ? <p><em>Loading Project...</em></p>
        : this.renderCreateForm(this.state.projectData.type, this.state.projectData.tech);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
            <h3>Project</h3>
            <hr />
            {contents}
        </div>
        )
}
```

If I want to add a new item, therefore using a default `PortfolioProject` object with default values, it works fine. However, if I want to edit an old entry, I have to grab it from the server, like so:

```
fetch('api/StuartAitkenWebsite/GetPortfolioProject/' + projID)
                .then(response => response.json() as Promise<PortfolioProject>)
                .then(data => {
                    this.setState({ title: "Edit", loading: false, projectData: data });
                });
```

In the debug console on Firefox, I can see the whole server process runs smoothly:

`GET http://localhost:62669/api/StuartAitkenWebsite/GetPortfolioProject/2`

```
Response payload: {"id":2,"name":"Particles Sim","projectDate":"2017-01-01T00:00:00","projectDurationWeeks":1,"type":"Desktop App","tech":"C++, SFML","views":0,"creationDate":"2018-10-22T00:00:00","modifiedDate":"2018-10-22T00:00:00","status":1}`
```

It gives a JSON output of the payload too, which I can't easily copy-paste here so I'll give a screenshot:

[image]

There are no server error responses, no React errors, nothing.

But that's as far as it gets.

The page remains showing 'loading', even though the data is there and ready and wants to be displayed.

From this, I can gather that the final step of the fetch call is not succeeding, because  `this.setState({ title: "Edit", loading: false, projectData: data });` is clearly not having any effect on the page data.

I have other fetch calls which look exactly the same but work fine. I can't see what I'm missing here.

The one and the only difference I notice is this:

When I use this component to create a fresh 'Add Project' form, the state is set like so:

```
this.state = {
            title: "Create",
            loading: false,
            projectData: new PortfolioProject,
        };
```

But when I do it from the API, it's set like so:

```
this.setState({
                    title: "Edit",
                    loading: false,
                    projectData: data
                });
```

The successful version uses `this.state`, and the unsuccessful version uses `this.setState`

I don't know what this can mean though. As I said, no errors are being thrown, I'm sticking to the tutorial format, and it works fine in other parts of the project.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I've put a log in at the point where `renderCreateForm()` is called. It seems `setState` is actually working. Therefore, the problem must be in  `renderCreateForm()` so I'll post that code below. Sorry it's sort of large.

```
private renderCreateForm(projectTypes: string, projectTech: string) {

    console.log(this.state.loading); // "false"
    console.log(this.state.projectData); //"Object { id:1, name: "Muon Detector".. etc 
//so the render is getting the data


    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSave}>
            <div className="form-group row" >
                <input type="hidden" name="Id" value={this.state.projectData.id} />
            </div>  
            <div className="form-group row" >
                <label className=" control-label col-md-12" htmlFor="Name">Name</label>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <input className="form-control" type="text" name="Name" defaultValue={this.state.projectData.name} required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group row" >
                <label className=" control-label col-md-12" htmlFor="ProjectDate">Project Date</label>
                <div className="col-md-4">

                    <input className="form-control" type="date" name="ProjectDate" defaultValue={this.state.projectData.creationDate.toDateString()} required />
                </div>
            </div >  
            <div className="form-group row" >
                <label className=" control-label col-md-12" htmlFor="ProjectDurationWeeks">Project Duration (weeks)</label>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <input className="form-control" type="text" name="ProjectDurationWeeks" defaultValue={this.state.projectData.projectDurationWeeks.toString()} required />
                </div>
            </div >  
            <div className="form-group row" >
                <label className=" control-label col-md-12" htmlFor="Type">Project Type</label>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <input className="form-control" type="text" name="Type" defaultValue={this.state.projectData.type} required />
                </div>
            </div >
            <div className="form-group row" >
                <label className=" control-label col-md-12" htmlFor="Tech">Project Tech</label>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <input className="form-control" type="text" name="Tech" defaultValue={this.state.projectData.tech} required />
                </div>
            </div >
            <div className="form-group row" >
                <input type="hidden" name="Views" value={this.state.projectData.views} />
            </div>  
            <div className="form-group row" >
                <input type="hidden" name="CreationDate" value={this.state.projectData.creationDate.toDateString()} />
            </div>  
            <div className="form-group row" >
                <input type="hidden" name="ModifiedDate" value={this.state.projectData.modifiedDate.toDateString()} />
            </div>  
            <div className="form-group row" >
                <input type="hidden" name="Status" value={this.state.projectData.status} />
            </div>  
            <div className="form-group">
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                <button className="btn" onClick={this.handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
            </div >  
        </form>
        )
}
```

**UPDATE 2**: Added some screenshots showing how things appear so far.

1. How the main data table page looks:

[image]

2. If I click 'Add New', it works:

[image]

(the 'Save' option works there too. Data posts to the server and will list on the main portfolio page)

3. Clicking Edit for any of the entries does not work, it gets this far:

[image]

The '*Loading Project...*' text comes from the `render()` call for this page, as is shown in the code posted at the top of this post.

The page is supposed to look exactly like the 'Create' page (2nd screenshot), but with the title being 'Edit', and with input values populated from the given data.

Comment: Please provide the code of this.renderCreateForm function, maybe the error is there. To be able to work with state you need to do `this.state = {...` in the overriden constructor of your component

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log()` something where you have the setState to confirm that it's being called?

Comment: And when you do fetch on promises, the `this` reference in the promise is the promise itself. So you can write something like this to get the component reference: 
                `let component = this;
                fetch('api/StuartAitkenWebsite/GetPortfolioProject/' + projID)
                .then(response => response.json() as Promise<PortfolioProject>)
                .then(data => {
                    component.setState({ title: "Edit", loading: false, projectData: data });
                });`

Comment: @SergeyGovyazin See update. Thanks.

Comment: @JJJ See update. Thanks.

Comment: @Stuart Aitken this code cannot show 'loading' after the data is fetched, because the `contents` now don't contain any 'loading' words. Maybe you can add some screenshots?

Comment: @SergeyGovyazin The '*loading...*' text comes from the original `render()` call (as seen in the 2nd code block from my post). I've added some screenshots to show how everything is looking at the moment.

Comment: Hm, don't know what can go bad in this code except my comment (#3 in this thread). Try to add `this.forceUpdate()` after `this.setState()` call, it should completely rerender the component

Comment: @Stuart Aitken yes, but when the `this.state.loading` is false and your `this.renderCreateForm` is called (when the log in your first question update is printed), the loading text cannot be rendered. It is strange

Comment: @SergeyGovyazin Indeed, very strange.... I've also tried your suggestion to use `let component = this`, and `component.forceUpdate()`, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was absurd, but may certainly help others...

The `renderCreateForm()` method (as shown in Update 1 of the post) was not working because of the `.toDateString()` method I was using in a few of the inputs.

I changed it to `.toString()` and now everything works.

For example, with an input like this:

```
<input className="form-control" type="date" name="ProjectDate" defaultValue={projectData.creationDate.toDateString()} required />
```

I changed it to this:

```
<input className="form-control" type="date" name="ProjectDate" defaultValue={projectData.creationDate.toString()} required />
```

Note the `defaultValue` property of the input.

Repeat for all cases of `.ToDateString()`, and it now works,

Amazing that this didn't bring up an error anywhere. I thought Typescript and all these various frameworks were supposed to get around the issue of Javascript silently failing like that. This has been my longest and most time-wasting 'silent fail error' ever, by a very long margin.